# Where is/was location of Corvoda (near Lezant), Cornwall, England?

Tags: 19th-century, england, cornwall, historical-gazetteer, burial-records

When my 4th great grandfather Joseph Binney was buried on 17 Jul 1829 at Lezant, Cornwall, England, his residence was given as Corvoda.

I have looked for Corvoda (and searched on Cordova as a possible variant) without success via general googling and at:

- [GENUKI Gazetteer](http://www.genuki.org.uk/big/Gazetteer/)
- [Vision of Britain](http://www.visionofbritain.org.uk/index.jsp)
- [Gazetteer of British Place Names](http://www.gazetteer.org.uk)
- [The Historical Gazetteer of England's Place-Names](http://www.placenames.org.uk/)

Does anyone know of the location Corvoda near Lezant?

---

http://www.cornwall-opc-database.org/search-database/more-info/?t=burials&id=1226443 is a link (subject to change) to the burial record that mentions this location.

Comment: My ancestor Joseph Sargent had a private baptism at this farm in 1824

Comment: I used to live there if there is any further info you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Carvoda**

Carvoda is/was a farm and settlement very close to Lezant (as shown on this modern [map](http://www.streetmap.co.uk/map.srf?x=233815&y=79059&z=120&sv=lezant&st=3&tl=Map%20of%20Lezant,%20Cornwall%20[Town]&searchp=ids.srf&mapp=map.srf)).

It is spelled Curvoda on an [earlier map (1883 Ordinance Survey)](http://maps.nls.uk/view/101438246#zoom=4&lat=4157&lon=4222&layers=BT).

[An Index to the Historical Place Names of Cornwall, vol 1](https://books.google.it/books?id=fxGkBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA325&lpg=PA325&dq=curvoda,%20lezant&source=bl&ots=_HK_c_Y3jk&sig=FgGizpMmwT3ed1APx2Y1SpuA_wA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1vVzVfvOO4WxUaHBgPAO&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=curvoda%2C%20lezant&f=false) has this entry:

> **Curvoda** - Lezant, farm (Symons, 1884); *Crevoada*, 1806; *Crevoada*,
>   *Curvoda*, 1884.

As a matter of interest, according to this [glossary](https://archive.org/stream/glossaryofcornis00bann#page/40/mode/2up) of Cornish words, Curvoda means "court by the wood".

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Carvoda, an isolated farm/hamlet, south of Launceston and then south east of the village of Lezant. It's quite close to the A388 Launceston-Callington-Saltash road but road access is only via B roads west of the main road.